# Behavior of multiprocessing.Pool on exception?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Suppose I have a program that looks like this:

```py
jobs = [list_of_values_to_consume_and_act]
with multiprocessing.Pool(8) as pool:
    results = pool.map(func, jobs)
```

And whatever is done in `func` can raise an exception due to external circumstances, so I can't prevent an exception from happening.

How will the pool behave on exception?

1. Will it only terminate the process that raised an exception and let other processes run and consume the jobs?
2. If yes, will it start another process to pick up the slack?
3. What about the job being handled by the dead process, will it be 'resubmitted' to the pool?
4. In any case, how do I 'retrieve' the exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No processes will be terminated at all. All calls to the target
   functions from within the pool's processes are wrapped in a
   `try...except` block. Incase an exception is caught, the process
   informs the appropriate handler thread in the main process which
   passes the exception forward so it can be re-rasied. Whether or not other jobs will execute depends on if the pool is still open. Incase you do not catch this re-raised exception, the main process (or the process that started the pool) will exit, automatically cleaning up open resources like the pool (so no tasks can be executed now since pool closed). But if you catch the exception and let the main process continue running then the pool will not shutdown and other jobs will execute as scheduled.
2. N/A
3. The outcome of a job is irrelevant, once it's *run* once by any process,
   that job is marked completed and not resubmitted to the pool.
4. Wrap your call to `pool.map` in a `try...except` block? Do note that
   incase one of your jobs do raise an error, then the results of other
   successful jobs will become inaccessible as well (because these are
   stored after the call to `pool.map` completes, but the call never
   successfully completed). In such cases, where you need to catch
   exceptions of individual jobs, it's better to use [`pool.imap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap)
   or [`pool.apply_async`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async)

Example of catching exception for individual tasks using `imap`:

```
import multiprocessing
import time


def prt(value):
    if value == 3:
        raise ValueError(f"Error for value {value}")
    
    time.sleep(1)
    return value


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with multiprocessing.Pool(3) as pool:
        jobs = pool.imap(prt, range(1, 10))
        results = []

        for i in range(10):
            try:
                result = next(jobs)
            except ValueError as e:
                print(e)
                results.append("N/A")  # This means that this individual task was unsuccessful
            except StopIteration:
                break
            else:
                results.append(result)

    print(results)
```

Example of catching exception for individual tasks using `apply_async`

```
import multiprocessing
import time


def prt(value):
    if value == 3:
        raise ValueError(f"Error for value {value}")

    time.sleep(1)
    return value


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(3)
    job = [pool.apply_async(prt, (i,)) for i in range(1, 10)]
    results = []
    
    for j in job:
        try:
            results.append(j.get())
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
            results.append("N/A") 

    print(results)
```

Comment: Thanks! I learnt so much from your very good explanation!