# How to maintain a pool of processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, multiprocessing-manager

I have a project in which I run multiple processes to do multiple jobs, the jobs are distributed via a queue.

```
queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
process = multiprocessing.spawn(
    run_alg,
    args=(queue,),
    nprocs=process_num,
    join=False,
)
process.join()
```

However, it is possible for the processes to stop working or to crash mid-operation.
I want to create a pool of x processes where every time a process is shut down, a new process will be created to take its place until the queue is empty.

Is it possible, how?

Comment: What is `multiprocessing.spawn`?

Comment: Are you just looking for a [`Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool)? Why do the processes "stop working or to crash"? If it's due to an exception, that won't cause a pool worker to terminate. See [Behavior of multiprocessing.Pool on exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74382683/11082165)

Comment: The process may fail for any number of reasons, it can receive a sigkill, for examples, which don’t raise an exception

Comment: How did you get on with my suggestion?

Comment: You wrote pseudo code, in practice I encountered errors and I searched for another route

Comment: I'm deleting it as it's not useful. Kindly share your preferred solution so we can all learn. Thank you.

Comment: Obviously when I will be able to program a working solution I will publish it

Comment: If you don't have a solution, how about showing your code thst generates errors rather than just discounting my suggestion?

Comment: I think it is too long for a comment, perhaps in a different post. But with all due respect, I think your answer was a bit basic, Don't you think you should give more than pseudo code, especially when I provided code and named the language? Perhaps this is a bit much to ask, or maybe my question wasn't clear enough, nevertheless, thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Mmm... you know your arguments, not me. So find your arguemts and call `subprocess.run()` with them. It shouldn't be hard. If that doesn't work, edit your question and show your updated code and error messages.